# Xcode forgot password Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, passwords, reset

```
- (IBAction)forgotPassword:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Direccion de Correo" message:@"Introduzca su correo electronico:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancelar" otherButtonTitles:@"Aceptar", nil];
    alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alertView show];


}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if(buttonIndex ==1){
        NSLog(@"ok button clicked in forgot password alert view");
        NSString *email=[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        if ([email isEqualToString:@"email"]) {
            UIAlertView *display;
            display=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email" message:@"Please enter password for resetting password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [display show];

        }else{
            [PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:email block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                UIAlertView *display;
                if(succeeded){
                    display=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Correo electronico enviado" message:@"Por favor, revise su correo para resetear contraseña" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

                }else{
                     display=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Correo fallido" message:@"el correo electronico no coincide con ninguno en la base de datos" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                }
                [display show];
            }];
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I would like to find the mistake in this code that don't let me see the second AlertView. If the user is found o not the same AlertView appears

Comment: I'll fix your code formatting, but you should add this explanation to your question. Because right now, it's really difficult to understand, what you're asking.

Comment: like I did feww minutes ago. Sorry, this is my first time here

Comment: the problem is exactly when if condition start. The first if condition works ok but the second is that does not let me see the second AlertView.

Answer (score 2):

In your below code,

```
//Here you fire the query to check for email address in your parse backend
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

if (!error) {  //If no error in your query then will enter below block

//the objects is array of object it gets from your parse but in your case it return's zero which implies that there is no object with that email in your parse db.

         if (objects.count ==0) {

//As objects.count is zero that means no email exist so in that case you don't send email for password recovery and show a alert as below to user that email is invalid(meaning not exist)

            UIAlertView *alertView =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Correo enviado" message:@"Por favor, revise su correo para resetear su contraseña" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancelar" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alertView show];

         } else {
 //In this, else case will enter when there is objects.count greater than zero which means that email exist on db. So, in that case you would request for password recovery as below.

 //Also could show a alert to let user know that request for password recovery was sent successfully.

            [self sendEmail:emailTextField.text];

             //the query was successful, but found 0 results
             //email does not exist in the database, dont send the email
             //show your alert view here
         }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

Why are again checking condition(objects == nil) as your doing in first condition(object.count == 0). Both are same so no point in showing alert for one reason. Also I ran your code and I was getting one alert to enter some text followed by a alert with title "Correo enviado".

If I misunderstand your query or anything else then please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback I really appreaciate. Yeah!! you are right. In fact, I just testing and at the end is a disaster. I know. Sorry. So; i guess i need to delete the second if but how i make to show the alertview when the email is not correct? thanks so much in advance.

Comment: For email alert ,when u get no objects returned from parse then that means no user with that email exist's on parse side so simply show alert with message that "Invalid email" and subtext as "Please provide a valid email" ,and then let user see your parent view of alertView.

Comment: Hello Walle84. I write again the code and I add some lines that I want to. I hope now it is more understandable. First, I want to add one line where the query was successful, but found 0 results and then email does not exist in the database, dont send the email. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @maytelabarga I have made changes in my post (code part explanation) and hope that it might help you out. If anything else please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Why you are going for multiple queries first to find User details if found send ResetPasswordRequest instead use completion handler for Reset Request.

```
[PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:self.txtEmail.text block:^(BOOL succeeded,NSError *error)
{

    if (!error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:kAlertTitle message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Link to reset the password has been send to specified email"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return;

    }
    else
    {
          NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:kAlertTitle message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Password reset failed: %@",errorString] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
}];
```

If user is not present Parse will respond with an error "Error: no user found with email xxxxxxxxx@xxx.com"

Regards,

Amit

Comment: Sorry, Amit but it does not work. I do not receive any email with this code. Thanks indeed.